# External method and action not working in demo

Tags: asp.net-core, rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

Using the unchanged CodeEffects asp.net core demo project (downloaded 25th Sept 2018) I encounter problems whenever I try to use external method *IsToday* or external action  *RequestInfo* in the rule editor.

The exception is thrown both when trying to save the rule or trying to test the rule. In both cases it throws in *HomeController* on the line

```
editor.LoadClientData(data.Data);
```

When using external method *IsToday* in the rule the exception is

```
CodeEffects.Rule.Common.SourceException: No method with "3A76579EC84ADAC52990336CA74D8E18" value of the "token" attribute found. (#112)
```

and when using external action *RequestInfo* the exception is

```
CodeEffects.Rule.Common.SourceException: No method with "[NULL]" value of the "token" attribute found. (#112)
```

No code changes have been made to the downloaded demo project at all. I've tried updating CodeEffects nuget packages in the project and it doesn't solve the problem.

If not using external method or action then the demo works without throwing the exception.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We found the solution to the issue you described. I'll post more info in comments shortly.

Comment: @Alex Any news regarding the solution to the problem?

Comment: The solution for this issue would really be helpful @Alex, please could you post it or give me some idea when this will be ready?

Comment: The new version 5.0.4.8 of the CodeEffects.Rule.Editor.Web.Core library published on nuget solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The new version 5.0.4.8 of the CodeEffects.Rule.Editor.Web.Core library published on nuget on October 21st 2018 solves the problem.